# Étale morphisms in SDG

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, deformation-theory, definitions, synthetic-differential

On page 70 [here](http://home.math.au.dk/kock/sdg99.pdf), Kock defines a formally étale morphism $f:M\rightarrow N$ as one for which the following square is a pullback for each $d:\mathbf 1\rightarrow D$
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} M^D @>{f^D}>> N^D\\ @V{M^d}VV @VV{N^d}V\\ M^\mathbf{1} @>>{f^\mathbf{1}}> N^\mathbf{1}. \end{CD}$$
Concretely this means the tangent space $M^D=TM$ is isomorphic to set of pairs $(t,x)\in N^D\times M$ satisfying $t(d)=f(x)$. This is not the same as just taking tangents whose basepoint $t(0)=f(x)$, so how is this definition equivalent to the one saying the induced map on tangent spaces is an iso?

Answer (score 4):

You have omitted a crucial part of the sentence:

> ... in the sense of §16.

The point is small objects admit canonical basepoints via the augmentation of the Weil algebras defining them. See [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775233/the-canonical-base-point-for-weil-algebras/1775332#1775332) for the definition of $\operatorname{Spec}_R(\pi)$ for the augmentation $\pi:W\rightarrow R$. The author's definition only asks for pullbacks involving these canonical base points.

For the dual numbers, this notion does pick zero as a basepoint, since dual numbers can be identified with $R^2$ with-dual-number-multiplication, making the projection of $\bar x=(0,x)$ clearly zero.